# Stacking 2 divs on top

Tags: html, css

I've used Bootstrap in the past but cannot find how to do a basic stacking of 2 divs, it's basically 2 col-lg-6 divs sat on top of each other but against one div to the left of it (see picture).

How should the HTML look for this? Should it all be in the one row or is there special classes for doing this?

[image]

Comment: Use two rows on top of each other

Answer (score 1):

so you will want a row, inside that row you want a `col-6` division. on the 2nd division, just add stuff

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hikopu/1/

---

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    [left]
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    [right]

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [right top]
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [right bottom]
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```